# AS3 How to detect startTouchDrag on Stage with no target?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, drag, stage

I'm really new to using Action Script in general and could use a good explanation on how to do this as well as how it works.

I'm trying to create a stage event in AS3 for Android.

When the user touches the stage and not an object in particular I need to detect if they are dragging and the location of where there finger has dragged to.

I've started like this to detect if they have touched the stage:

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, stageTouchBegin); 

var stageTouchDragBounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

function stageTouchBegin(event:TouchEvent):void
{
event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, stageTouchDragBounds:Rectangle);
trace(event.stageX);
trace(event.stageY);
}
```

**This line is where I get the error** and I'm assuming that it's because target would typically be referencing a movie symbol or something but in this case it's not because its the stage. I tried replacing target with stage but it didn't work:

`event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, stageTouchDragBounds:Rectangle);`

**Here is the error**:  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method startTouchDrag through a reference with static type flash.events:TouchEvent.

---

From there my plan was to proceed to use something like this to start recording where they were at:

`var curPosX;
var curPosY;`

```
function stageTouchMoveHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{   
trace(event.stageX);
this.curPosX = event.stageX;
trace(event.stageY);
this.curPosY = event.stageY;
}
```

Then handle the ending as such:

```
function stageTouchEndHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
event.target.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
}
```

Any insight/advice on how to do this or an explanation of target, especially example code, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Perhaps you're not clear on what the `startTouchDrag()` method is supposed to do. It's meant for actually dragging an object, like in a drag and drop operation. The stage is not something you can drag around the screen. You can only use the `startTouchDrag()` method on objects that are or extend the `Sprite` class (of which the stage is not). I'm not super skilled on touch events, otherwise I'd offer more advice. But it's definitely not possible to use `startTouchDrag()` with the stage :) Try reading [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about what you are trying to do, I think the answer to your question is don't call the `startTouchDrag()` method and proceed w/your plans. What you have shown is the right approach to determine where the user started/stopped their "touch move" gesture.

It makes no sense to try and drag the `stage` ... the `stage` is literally a stage that your Flash movie is shown on. It contains the entire Flash application, and as such cannot be dragged.

To reiterate what I stated in my comment above, `startTouchDrag()` is a method you call on a Sprite (or some object that extends `Sprite`). This method is meant to be used when you want to drag something across the screen, like in a drag and drop operation.

Comment: What you've said makes sense. I'm just struggling to find how I can track their movement, I'm not really sure what to search for. My stageTouchBegin function can provide me with the coordinates for their touch easily enough, but I don't know how to make it keep tracking their movement until release.

Comment: @Eric I highly recommend reading the Adobe article in the comment that I linked to above. The last code example, does something very similar to what you are doing. Since touch gestures can involve more than one "touch point" they use the the event's `touchPointID` property to determine "which finger" the event is coming from. When the touch finally ends, just determine the x/y coordinates for the end, and compare w/the coords from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Sunil, I got it working with your guidance. It just took me a while to understand how to use the touchPoint and the event correctly. It was just like you said though, I don't need the startTouchDrag(). I just needed to recall the event in my function:
    `stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, stageTouchMoveHandler);`

    `function stageTouchMoveHandler(event:TouchEvent):void` Then it gives me the current position that the user is at on the fly.